# Copy struct to char[] buffer

Tags: c++, structure, memcpy

I have to copy the following structure to a char[] buffer.

```
 struct AMG_ANGLES {        
            unsigned char bIsEnCrypted;
            unsigned char bIsError;
            unsigned short      usErrorFlag;
            unsigned char byteNumDABs;
            unsigned short      usBagId;
            unsigned short      usKvMa;
            unsigned char byteDataType;
    };

            AMG_ANGLES struct_data;
            struct_data.bIsEnCrypted = 1;
            struct_data.bIsError = 1;
            struct_data.usErrorFlag = 2;
            struct_data.byteNumDABs = 1;
            struct_data.usBagId =10;
            struct_data.usKvMa=20;
            struct_data.byteDataType = 1;

// here I am coping structure to a char buffer
char sendbuf[sizeof(struct_data)] = "";
memcpy(sendbuf,(char*)&struct_data, sizeof(struct_data));
```

on copy the buffer having  first two unsigned char data and short (1,1,2) and size is only 3 bytes. reaming data was not copying.
Please help where i am doing wrong.

I tried following way also

```
        memcpy(sendbuf+0, &struct_data.bIsEnCrypted, sizeof(struct_data.bIsEnCrypted));
        memcpy(sendbuf+1, &struct_data.bIsError, sizeof(struct_data.bIsError));
        memcpy(sendbuf+2, &struct_data.usErrorFlag, sizeof(struct_data.usErrorFlag));
        memcpy(sendbuf+4, &struct_data.byteNumDABs, sizeof(struct_data.byteNumDABs));
        memcpy(sendbuf+6, &struct_data.usBagId, sizeof(struct_data.usBagId));   
        memcpy(sendbuf+8, &struct_data.usKvMa, sizeof(struct_data.usKvMa));
        memcpy(sendbuf+10, &struct_data.byteDataType, sizeof(struct_data.byteDataType));
```

same result I am getting.

Comment: If you put members of the same type together your struct may be more compact in memory.

Comment: Also be aware that different compilers and the same compiler on a different setting may pad the struct differently.

Comment: after memcpy i am printing strlen of sendbuf                                                 int n = strlen(sendbuf); i am getting n value as 3 only and same is sending to server app.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine; your approach to determine whether the contents of the buffer are correct is flawed.

You have not told us how you have determined that the contents of the buffer are wrong, but from your description I suspect that you did something like `printf( "%s\n", sendbuf )`.  Well, that won't work, because your buffer does not really contain characters, it contains binary data.

Specifically, your `short usErrorFlag` is two bytes long, and since the value you store in it is `2`, this means that it will be stored in `sendbuf` in two consecutive bytes, one byte will have the value of `0x02` and the next byte will have the value of `0x00`.  (Assuming, from hints in your description, that your hardware is "Little Endian".)  So, when you try to view the contents of your `sendbuf` as a string, `printf()` will stop printing as soon as it encounters the `0x00` byte.

So, your code is correct.  Proceed with sending your `sendbuf` to your UDP socket.

Answer (score 2):

If I read "sendbuf" I immediately assume that you are sending data from one computer to another. These computers will have different compilers, the compilers will for example order their bytes in a different order. memcpy isn't going to work on all compilers.

I suggest you find where the contents of sendbuf is documented, and assign the individual bytes accordingly. For example

```
sendbuf [0] = struct_data.bIsEncrypted;
sendbuf [1] = struct_data.bIsError;
sendbuf [2] = struct_data.uIsErrorFlag >> 8;
sendbuf [3] = struct_data.uIsErrorFlag & 0xff;
```

This makes your code independent of byte ordering, independent of struct padding, independent of reordering of items once you are not using a POD, and so on. In your case I would bet money that there is at least padding between byteNumDABs and usBagId, and at the end.

(Bytes 2 and 3 might be exactly the other way round, that's why you find a spec for that data structure).